# how to apply lag and lag rolling mean multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

How to apply lag and lag rolling on multiple columns in a easy. I can apply on single by single column but I need apply on many columns more efficiently

```
ppt <- ts(rep(c(5,6,7,8,11,13,14,15,16,15,14,17,13,12,15,13,12,12,11,10,9,8,7,6), 10)*runif(120,0.8,1.2), freq = 24)
col <- c(1:20)
data <- data.frame(lapply(col, function(x) ppt[x:(110+x)])) # create a design matrix
colnames(data) <- c(paste0("x_",as.character(c(1:19))),"y")

data <- data %>%

  mutate(lag_1 = lag(y, 1)
         , avg_3 = lag(roll_meanr(y, 3), 1)
         , avg_2 = lag(roll_meanr(y, 2), 1)

  )
```

Comment: I'm guessing `library(dplyr)` and `library(RcppRoll)` should be added to the code.

Comment: If you're doing the same thing to lots of columns, `mutate_at`/`mutate_all`. If you're doing lots of things with one column, iterate into a list column and `unnest`.